# What is the difference between flow work and kinetic energy in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, flow

I'm having a hard time understanding what the difference between flow energy and kinetic energy in a fluid that moves. My book gives me the following equation for mechanical energy of flowing fluid:

[image]

Now the two last terms is easy to understand for me, but I don't see the necessity for the first term. Surely all the energy tied to the fluids movement is contained in the kinetic energy of the fluid?

If possible I would really appreciate an intuitive answer.

Comment: "*Surely all the energy tied to the fluids movement is contained in the kinetic energy of the fluid?*" Surely some energy tied to the fluid's movement must be associated with the fluid at pressure $P$ that it has to push aside (alternatively, the pressure head $P$ available to accelerate it)?

Comment: Sure I can see that there is some inherent energy in the pressure of the fluid, but flow energy is specifically mentioned in flowing fluid. As the flow work somehow is responsible for the energy of a fluid that leaves a boundary and not the kinetic energy. 
That I just don't get

Answer (score 2):

You can consider pressure as energy density. Note:

$$P=\frac{F}{A}=\frac{Fd}{Ad}=\frac{W}{V}$$

When flow encounters a restriction, the pressure, and thus pressure energy, drops. This may seem counter intuitive until you realize that at the same time the flow velocity and thus kinetic energy increases at the restriction.

For a given elevation, neglecting friction losses, conservation of energy requires  any increase in kinetic energy in the flow equal any decrease in pressure energy in the flow due to the flow work done per unit volume pushing the fluid through the restriction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but how can pressure drop if the flow encounters a restriction? Shouldn't that increase pressure? Like when you squeeze on a garden hose, it increases the pressure. 

I think I see your point with the formula - is it wrong to consider the flow work as a kind of energy potential? Would a non-flowing fluid have flow work/energy in it?

Comment: @JanF.S it is counter intuitive but nonetheless true as discussed here  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pber.html

Comment: @JanF.S see update to my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Well the pressure reduction due to restriction makes sense to me now. But I still struggle to see the need for the term flow work. 
But thanks though

Comment: @JanF.S are you familiar with the work energy principle?

Comment: absolutely. I can see how pv is equal to work. THe main point im missing is just how if a flowing fluid does work on something, why you can't express this work through the kinetic energy? 

I just read another answer to a similar question which basically said that the pressure energy is like a potential energy

Answer (score 2):

Consider a small moving mass $dm$ crossing a fixed boundary $L$. Work ${p \over \rho} dm$ is required to push the mass across the boundary. ${p \over \rho}$ is the work per unit mass.  This is the Lagrangian viewpoint, following a fixed mass.

Consider mass flowing into a fixed region. This is the Eulerian viewpoint, following a fixed region, and the system is called an open thermodynamic system. From this viewpoint, ${p \over \rho}$ is called flow energy.

This is why in the first law of thermodynamics for mass entering/leaving an open system, The enthalpy, $h$ of the flowing masses is considered, where $h = u + {p \over \rho}$, $u$ being the internal energy of the flowing fluid.

Your relationship for mechanical energy is used in the Bernoulli equation, which is an approximation of the first law for an incompressible fluid with negligible changes in internal energy.  Sometimes the Bernoulli equation includes terms for work done (e.g. by a pump) and the "head" loss due to friction to simply account for change in internal energy. The Bernoulli equation is not true in general, for example where there are large changes in the temperature of the fluid.

See a good book on thermodynamics such as Obert, Thermodynamics.  For a detailed development see Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot.

Answer (score 1):

This term is defined for a flowing fluid. Your perspective is somewhat as though you are standing inside the fluid and wanting to consider all forces (kinetic, potential, and pressure) on the fluid contributing to energy density. You are able to account for the kinetic and potential energy terms for that fluid, but you wonder about the pressure term. Stand instead inside a static control volume, allow the fluid to flow through it, and consider the energy balance.

The energy balance equation (conservation of energy equation) over the static control volume is stated using internal energy $\tilde{U}$, kinetic energy $\tilde{E}_K$, and potential energy $\tilde{E}_p$, each here expressed per unit mass. Within the defined control volume, we write terms for flow in/out, change with time, and heat + work as

$$\iint_{CS} \left( \tilde{e} + \frac{p}{\rho}\right) \rho \left(\vec{v}\bullet\vec{n}\right) dA + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \iiint_{CV} \rho\ \tilde{e}\ dV = \dot{q} - \dot{w}$$

with

$$\tilde{e} \equiv \tilde{U} + \frac{v^2}{2} + gz$$

The first integral is over the control surface (CS). It accounts for energy flow into and out of the system through its boundary. The second integral is over the control volume (CV). It accounts for energy change inside the volume as a function of time (the derivative).

A closed system would not consider the first term because no mass flows into or out from the control surface. Notice then that we have no consideration for the $p/\rho$ term. Heat or work flow change either the internal, kinetic, or potential energy of the control volume with time.

For an open system, the mass that flows into or out from the control volume carries energy density with it. The first energy density is the internal + kinetic + potential as for any control volume. We include an additional energy density term for potential to do $pV$ work as the fluid packet moves through the control volume. We translate $pV$ work into an energy density using

$$\frac{pV}{m} = p\tilde{V} = \frac{p}{\rho}$$

This is not work to ''push'' fluid into or out of the control volume. This is a *capacity* for the fluid packet to expand or contract as the it passes through the control volume. If the term $p/\rho$ is the same at the exit as the entrance, the fluid packet has neither expanded nor contracted as it passes through the control volume.

Using your definition, we obtain

$$\tilde{e} = \tilde{U} + \tilde{e}_{mech}$$

Finally, consider a steady state, adiabatic process. The time derivative and heat flow terms are zero. Allow the fluid to have the same entering and exit velocities and heights. We obtain

$$\iint_{CS} \left(\frac{p}{\rho}\right) \rho \left(\vec{v}\bullet\vec{n}\right) dA = - \dot{w}$$

The static control volume will expand or contract according to the change in the $p/\rho$ term going into and out of the control volume.

Comment: Appreciate the  detailed answer although I can't really follow the integrals. 
So this means that there is no flow work for a fluid that does not leave a system boundary?
So in your open system example, if the fluid pushes something while moving a certain distance, that would result in a higher energy density and therefore higher pressure? Due to bernoulli's equation?

Comment: I've added an explanation for the integrals and an explanation for the $p/\rho$ term. Do not consider that energy density in the fluid packet being changed because it pushes (or pulls) other fluid packets. Consider only what happens to energy density terms for internal energy (temperature), kinetic energy (velocity), potential energy (height), and *capacity to expand/contract* ($p/\rho$) as you sit on the fluid packet while it is moving through the control volume.